# Java, converting Calendar format to Date(YYYY-MM-DD)

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.setTime(LeaveDate);
    calendar1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, ProcessDate);
    Date fullDate1 = calendar1.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Here the output i.e., date1 is string, how to convert it to Date

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please give an example of your input and wanted output.
What is `LeaveDate` and `ProcessDate` ?  If you are not familiar with Stackoverflow yet, take the [tour], read [ask] first. What we need is a [example].

Comment: `date1` is not a "string", it's `SimpleDateFormat`. Are you confused about how to use a `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: How to use SimpleDateFormat, that's easy: don't! Seriously. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Reading your code, apparently you want to take the current moment as seen in the current default time zone, adjust to a particular day of month, and then convert to a moment as seen in UTC to be represented by the outmoded class [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html).

```
java.util.Date          // Legacy class. Replaced by `java.time.Instant`.
.from(                  // New conversion method added to old class, to move between legacy and modern classes.
    ZonedDateTime       // Represents a moment as seen in a particular time zone.
    .now()              // Implicitly applies the JVM’s current default time zone.
    .withDayOfMonth( yourDesiredDayOfMonthGoesHere )  // Adjust to another moment on another date. Returns another `ZonedDateTime` object immutably, rather than altering original.
    .toInstant()        // Adjust from time zone to UTC. Same moment, different wall-clock time.
)                       // Returns an object for the same moment, but as a legacy `Date` object. Avoid using this class if at all possible.
```

But your title asks for something different. The title asks how to generate text in a [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format (YYYY-MM-DD) for a `Calendar` object.  Assuming your [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html) object is a [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) object, we can cast. Then we can convert to the modern [`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object, extract the date-only [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) object, and generate standard text. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text, so no need for a formatting pattern.

```
(GregorianCalendar) yourCalendarHere  // Cast from the more general `Calendar` to the more specific `GregorianCalendar`. 
.toZonedDateTime()                    // Convert from legacy class to modern. Same moment in the same time zone. Returns a `java.time.ZonedDateTime` object.
.toLocalDate()                        // Strip away the time zone and the time-of-day, leaving only the date. Returns a `java.time.LocalDate` object.
.toString()                           // Generate text representing the value of that date in standard ISO 8601 format, YYYY-MM-DD. Returns a `String` object.
```

Tip: Stop using the terribly flawed legacy date-time classes. Use only *java.time*.

## Formatters

> Here the output i.e., date1 is string, how to convert it to Date

You seem to misunderstand the classes involved.

Your `date1` is a variable declared to be a `SimpleDateFormat` object. That class is a *formatter*. As a formatter, its job is to *generate* text, not hold text nor hold a date. So your variable is misnamed, as it does not hold a date.

## Avoid legacy classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Never use `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and such.

## *java.time*

Replace this:

```
 Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
```

… with this:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now() ;  // Implicitly uses the JVM’s current default time zone.
```

I assume that in this code:

```
calendar1.setTime(LeaveDate);
```

… the `LeaveDate` (should have been named with initial lowercase, `leaveDate`) represents a `java.util.Date` object. And you are trying to get a calendar object set to the moment represented by that `Date` object.

In *java.time*, we use [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). So, no use of `set` methods. In *java.time*, if handed a `java.util.Date` object, immediately convert to an `Instant`. Both classes represent a moment as seen in UTC, with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds. To convert, use the new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = leaveDate.toInstant() ;
```

Adjust that moment into a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ; // The JVM’s current default time zone.
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Both `instant` & `zdt` represent the same moment, the very same point on the timeline. But their date and time-of-day are adjusted for the wall-clock time used by the people of two different regions. If someone in Iceland, where they use UTC as their time zone, called someone in Tokyo, and both people looked up to see the calendar and clock on their respective walls, they would see a different time and possibly a different date.

In your line:

```
calendar1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, ProcessDate);
```

… I am guessing that you want to set the day-of-month while keeping the same month, year, and time-of-day. For example, let's use the 23rd. Notice that we generate a new `ZonedDateTime` rather than alter ("mutate") the original. Adjustments are made automatically if the result would be impossible, such as the 30th of February.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtForSpecificDayOfMonth = zdt.withDayOfMonth( 23 ) ;  // Change day-of-month to the 23rd.
```

Regarding your line:

```
Date fullDate1 = calendar1.getTime();
```

… as I said above, you should avoid using `Date` in modern Java. But if you must do so to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, extract an `Instant` from the `ZonedDateTime` object, and convert to a `java.util.Date`.

```
Instant instant = zdtForSpecificDayOfMonth.toInstant() ;  // Adjust from a time zone to an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds. 
java.util.Date d = Date.from( instant ) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Parsing dates in Java with `DateFormat` or descendants

Tested with Java's REPL `jshell`

```
jshell> import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
jshell> var df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
df ==> java.text.SimpleDateFormat@f67a0200
jshell> Date dt =  df.parse("2022-02-15");
dt ==> Tue Feb 15 00:00:00 CET 2022
```

Read the official JavaDoc for class [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to figure out how to use it to parse a String to Date:

```java
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date dt =  df.parse("2022-02-15");
System.out.println(dt); // prints Tue Feb 15 00:00:00 CET 2022
```

Explained:

- The `"yyyy-MM-dd"` as argument to the constructor is a date-format literal (representing ISO-date format).
- The [`parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) method parses a String with this format and returns the `Date` object if valid format, or throws a [`ParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html).

Or search Stackoverflow for [`[java] String to Date`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+String+to+Date) to find similar questions.

#### Formatting dates in Java with `DateFormat` or descendants

The other way round you can also format a `Date` object to have a well-formatted String representation. Use the [`format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)) method of your `DateFormat` instance:

```java
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date dt =  df.parse("2022-02-15");

String formatted = df.format(dt);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

For example to format your `Calendar` instance use:

```java
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();

//  whatever modifies the calendar left out here

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formatted = df.format(dt);
System.out.println(calendar1.getTime());
```